# Gulp error: Did you forget to signal async completion?

Tags: javascript, gulp

Problems with compiling what I see as a simple script using gulp. When ran it causes a "Did you forget to signal async completion?" error.

Looking at the internet this seems to be a problem with async functions and read that passing and adding the done function would resolve this. In my case this isn't the case so wondering what else I'm doing wrong.

```
gulp.task("compile-less", done => {
  gulp
    .src("./app/design/frontend/Playsports/theme_frontend_base/web/css/_base.less")
    .pipe(less())
    .pipe(
      gulp.dest(() => {
        return "./pub/static/frontend/Playsports/gcn/en_GB/css/";
      })
    );
  done();
});

gulp.task("default", done => {
  gulp.series("compile-less");
  done();
});
```

I would expect this to not error and complete the task.

Answer (score 0):

This would be the general form:

```
gulp.task("default", gulp.series("compile-less", done => {
  // do something else here
  done();
}));
```

In your case I believe this is sufficient:

```
gulp.task("default", gulp.series("compile-less"));
```